# Firebase instead of rails for backend

Tags: ruby-on-rails, firebase, react-native-firebase

I’m used to developing in rails for the web. So when I want to fetch records matching specific fields and then manipulate the data as I see fit, I can easily do it with Rails.
However, I am now developing an Expo app and want to give Firebase a try.
To do what I described above, can that be achieved entirely on Firebase? Is it done with Cloud Functions?
Is there something I am missing about Firebase in that respect I should know?